# missing ) after argument list when comparing strings

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button that triggers the function `compareArea()`. It looks like this:

```
<button id="compare" onclick="compareArea()" type="button">Compare</button>

<script>
    function compareArea() {
        alert("string1"~ = "string2");
    }
</script>
```

However, I have the error returned `missing ) after argument list`. What's gone wrong?

Comment: Use `==` instead of `~=`.

Comment: However, this returns a boolean value - what if I want an integer of how many letters don't match? @Kinduser

Comment: What do you mean by "how many letters don't match." Fuzzy comparison of strings is a complicated topic and you'd have to explain which algorithm is preferable to you.

Comment: You would need to craft such a function, by checking each letter individually.

Comment: I was reading a few posts on this topic, and one person suggested using `sum( str1 == str2 )` to find how many letters are out of place. However, `sum` isn't a defined function, and using ~= gives me an error, so I wanted to see where I went wrong @gyre @obsidianage

Comment: `~=` is not a Javascript operator. It seems to exist in a few other languages, though I can't find any language where it would do what you're looking for. You might want to look into the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no simple comparison that tells you how many characters differ. What you could do is:

1. Check which of the strings is shorter. There is no problem here if both strings are of the same length but once one is shorter than the other we reach a dead end when iterating over them.
2. Iterate over all the characters, compare each one of them.
3. Increase a counter with every mismatch.

It could look like this:

```
<button id="compare" onclick="compareArea()" type="button">Compare</button>

<script>
  function compareArea() {
    var string1 = "string1";
    var string2 = "string2";
    var shortest;
    var count = 0;

    if(string1.length === string2.length) {
      shortest = string1;
    } else if(string1.length < string2.length) {
      shortest = string1;
      count = string2.length - string1.length;
    } else if(string1.length > string2.length) {
      shortest = string2;
      count = string1.length - string2.length;
    }

    for (var i=0; i < shortest.length; i++) {
     if(string1.charAt(i) !== string2.charAt(i)) {
       count++;
     }
    }
    alert(count);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Felix. This makes sense. Just what I was looking for. @Felix